# Rerun CodedUI test in runtime

Tags: c#, .net, coded-ui-tests

I have a CodedUI test. It sporadic fail by exception(can't focus element). Can I do something like this

```
[TestMethod]
public void MySporadicFailedTest()
{
        try {
          //Some Test action
        }
        catch((Exception ex)) {
          if (ex is System.Exception.ElementNotFocused){
            //retry test
          }
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes. But, if that exception is thrown then why do you expect just retrying the test will do anything better? I suggest you do some web searches for debugging Coded UI tests and for handling the error message that was reported. Putting the full error message into the question here would have been a good idea.

Comment: Error isn't important in my question. I can try to avoid it. I'm interested in the possibility of restarting the test.

Comment: The `[TestMethod]` is just C# code. You can do whatever you can write in C#. The problem would seem to be whether it makes sense for your application under test (AUT); only you can decide that. You need to consider what the `retry test` code does. Does it properly restart the AUT or does it leave it at some unknown place in its execution? Generally a "*sporadic fail by exception*" means a bug in the AUT or a bug in the test suite. Just retrying the test is a bit like "*hopefully rebooting the computer will fix it*".

Answer (score 1):

This is something I deal with frequently when writing Coded UI tests. I almost always end up writing a simple extension method to handle retrying *specific actions* (not the entire test!). Sometimes, especially on pages with weird, non-standard markup or lots of AJAXy things happening, you'll just hit a situation where an action will fail one second because something isn't ready yet, then pass the next.

```
public static class TestRetryExtensions 
{
    public static void WithRetry<T>(this Action thingToTry, int timeout = 30) where T: Exception
    {
        var expiration = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(timeout)
        while (true) 
        {
            try 
            {
                thingToTry();
                return;
            }
            catch (T) 
            {
                if (DateTime.Now > expiration) 
                {
                    throw;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, within my actual test:

```
uiMap.ClickSomeThing();
uiMap.EnterSomeText();
Action clickSomeOtherThingAction = () => uiMap.ClickSomeOtherThingThatFailsForNoReason();
clickSomeOtherThingAction.WithRetry<UITestControlHiddenException>(60);
```

It tries to perform the action. If it fails with an exception that you aren't aware of being an occasional "normal" thing, it throws the exception as normal. If it fails with an exception that you're telling it to retry on, it will keep trying that action (with a 1 second delay between retries) until the timeout is exceeded, at which point it just gives up and rethrows the exception.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can catch which ever exception is thrown, you can wrap your test code in a retry loop.  Then it will try the test code a certain number of times before giving up:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < TimesToRetry; i++)
 {
     try{
        //perform test

        //test ran correctly - break out loop to end test
        break;
     }
     catch(Exception){
        //might want to log exception
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the codedUI test continuously failing without proper reason you can added some code to enhance the test and make it fail safe. If test failing specifically when focusing to an element try to give focus to upper level element first and then try focusing child elements. This [LINK](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/08/10/configuring-playback-in-vstt-2010.aspx) may help you to write fail safe test cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
 we can include below line of code in test clean up method to re run the     failed  script
if (TestContext.CurrentTestOutCome==TestContext.unittestoutcome.failed)
{
  var type=Type.GetType(TestContext.FullyQualifiedTestClassName);
  if (type !=null)
   {
     var method=Type.GetMethod(TestContext.TestName);
     var event=Activator.CreateInstance(type);
   }
 method.invoke(event);
```

}

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.